# Converting JPG to base64 and back

Tags: powershell

I can convert a jpeg to a base64 string using the following PowerShell command

```
[Convert]::ToBase64String((Get-Content -Path .\Capture.jpg -Encoding Byte)) >> capture.txt
```

I tried converting it back using the following

```
[Convert]::FromBase64String((Get-Content -Path .\capture.txt)) >> capture2.jpg
```

But I get a list of numbers and not a binary file. How do I convert the base64 file back to binary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write bytes to a file natively in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855705/write-bytes-to-a-file-natively-in-powershell). Be sure to check the highest voted answer.

Comment: Appending with `>>` will by default output in UTF16LE encoding, so b64 quadruples the file size and UTF16LE again doubles. Better pipe to `Set-Content` or `Out-File` with encoding parameter.

Comment: Please elaborate on the background of your question: If it concerns just a binary file, I agree that this is a duplicate (and you might actually just copy the file using [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-6)). What Is the is reason you trying to use `Code64` and why do you explicitly mention `JPG` in the title of your question?

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert that solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle it as a image you might want to rebuild it in memory (use it or make modifications) and then save it, like:

```
$Base64 = Get-Content -Raw -Path .\capture.txt
$Image = [Drawing.Bitmap]::FromStream([IO.MemoryStream][Convert]::FromBase64String($Base64))
$Image.Save("<path>\Image2.jpg")
```